# Future.cancel() is not cancelling the scheduled execution of ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I am scheduling a task as:

```
ScheduledExecutorService dataService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
Future<?> dataTimerHandle = dataService.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 100, freq, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

This works fine without a flaw.

However, when a certain flag becomes `true` on user action, the task is no more required periodically, and needs to be executed just once. I then attempt cancelling the task and submitting it just once as follows:

```
if(!dynamicUpdate) {
    dataTimerHandle.cancel(true); 
    dataTimerHandle = dataService.submit(runnable);
}
else { //Reschedule again:
    dataTimerHandle = dataService.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 100, freq, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

But seems like the runnable is still executing periodically and `cancel()` is not working as expected.
Is there an alternate strategy for this?

Comment: Please aso consider that the scheduling can be stopped and resumed whenever the flag 'dynamicUpdate' is re/set.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is probably not in the Future's `cancel()` method. Here is a small runnable example that appears to be doing exactly what you want:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class CancelPeriodicTask {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduler = (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        scheduler.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true);
        try {
            new CancelPeriodicTask().test(scheduler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            int openTasks = scheduler.shutdownNow().size();
            println("Finished, open tasks: " + openTasks);
            // openTasks will be 1 when RemoveOnCancelPolicy is false
            // and the executor is closed within the scheduled task-period.
        }
    }

    private static long sleepTime = 25L;

    public void test(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduler) throws Exception {

        // sleep 5 times at scheduled interval
        SleepTask sleepTask;
        ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledSleep = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(sleepTask = new SleepTask(), 0, 2 * sleepTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        sleepTask.sleepTimes.await();
        println("Cancelling scheduledSleep. Done: " + scheduledSleep.isDone() + ", cancelled: " + scheduledSleep.isCancelled());
        scheduledSleep.cancel(true);
        Thread.sleep(2 * sleepTime);
        println("Running sleepTask once.");
        scheduler.submit(sleepTask);
        Thread.sleep(2 * sleepTime);
        scheduledSleep = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(sleepTask, 0, 2 * sleepTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        println("Re-scheduled scheduledSleep. Done: " + scheduledSleep.isDone() + ", cancelled: " + scheduledSleep.isCancelled());
        Thread.sleep(5 * sleepTime);
        println("Cancelling scheduledSleep. Done: " + scheduledSleep.isDone() + ", cancelled: " + scheduledSleep.isCancelled());
        scheduledSleep.cancel(true);
    }

    class SleepTask implements Runnable {

        public final CountDownLatch sleepTimes = new CountDownLatch(5); 
        public int sleepCount;

        @Override public void run() {
            println("Sleeping " + (++sleepCount));
            try { Thread.sleep(sleepTime); } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sleepTimes.countDown();
        }
    }

    private static final long START_TIME = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

    private static void println(String msg) {
        System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - START_TIME) + "\t " + msg);
    }

}
```

Comment: This was really helful. I tried running the scripts without scheduler.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true); and noticed no difference. If you could also help with the side effects of this. Also, is it really required to wait after each cancellation as you have mentioned by Thread.sleep() before each re-schedulling. I don't want to wait for the runnable to finish the run.

Comment: @abksrv It is not needed to wait after each cancellation, it is just there in the example to show the task is no longer scheduled. The RemoveOnCancel only affects when the task is removed from the pool: normally it is only removed from the pool at the next scheduled run.

Comment: Thank you!!! Only one complain on answer. I think that `scheduler.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true);` is key factor here. That was issue in my case, where after `scheduledFuture.cancel(true)`I would get one more unwanted execution. I'm pretty sure that setRemoveOnCancel should be emphasised in answer, and answer should be marked as correct.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected since you are sending the cancel command to the wrong handle. When you call `service.submit()` it returns a handle for the newly created future, and you can't use the very same handle to send cancel messages to future's created via other calls

Obviously you can shut down the executor service via `sevice.shutdown()` to not start any runnable submitted after a certain moment

Comment: Please refer to the edited question above. I'm updating the handle. I'm not sure if I can use shutdown() because the flag 'dynamicUpdate' may become true any time and the schedular has to follow in that case.

Comment: You seem to reassign the handle every time the loop iterates, so it can't work. Please, post more code and more requirements

Answer (score 0):

I think, future.cancel method interrupts the thread the RUNNING thread, so you would need to catch the InterruptedException in the runnable class & just return;